# Differentiation between javax.persistence, javax.persistence-api and javaee-api

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm confused about the differences and the contents of javax.persistence, javax.persistence-api and javaee-api. The javaee-api may contain a lot more, but i'm only interested in the JPA stuff (if exist in javaee-api). On an abstract perspective there is JPA as specification and some implementation of JPA like eclipselink. Therefore it would be easy to understood if there would be two dependencies in a configuration: one for specification content and one for the implementation. But it seems that this is a bit more complicated, so i have the following questions:

- I assume "javax.persistence-api" contains stuff like interfaces and therefore javax.persistence-api contains the programmatic content declarations of the JPA without implementing the specification. So if i set javax.persistence-api in version 2.2 as dependency (maven or gradle) i define that JPA 2.2 must be used (must be supported by implementation) and if i set javax.persistence-api in version 2.1 as dependency i define that JPA 2.1 must be used/supported. Is that right ?
- What is the purpose/content of the "javax.persistence" dependency (downloadable for example in [this mvn repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence/2.2.1) in version 2.2.1) ?
- Does [javaee-api in version 7.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) already contain the javax.persistence-api and if so, which version? 2.1 ? How or where can i discover this information ?
- If i use the newest possible implementation, like EclipseLink 2.7.4 (in the first quarter of 2019) which states it supports JPA 2.2, is there any backward compatibility to older JPA versions like 2.1 ?

I would be very glad for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API dependencies are used to `compile` your project. The implementation can either be `provided` by a runtime (e.g. Java EE application server) or the application can be build to include the implementation. If you're not familiar with maven scopes, I suggest you read [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

- You're right, `javax.persistence-api` does not include the implementation.
- [that maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence/2.2.1) is an eclipselink implementation. The artifactId is changed in version 2.3 from "javax.persistence" to "eclipselink".
- [javaee-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) includes also the JPA. Api version can be found for example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview007.htm): "*The Java EE 7 platform requires Java Persistence API 2.1.*" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_profile) also has a comparison of API versions of the web profile, which may clear things up (web profile is a subset of the Java EE spec).
- I don't know about the compatibility between JPA 2.1/2.2 versions. I would always use the same implementation version.

edit: I guess you could run JPA 2.1 application in a JPA 2.2 runtime. However, backward compatibility should also mean there are no ***behavioral differences***. New version has more features, and those features might be enabled by default. After all, Java EE is all about "convention over configuration". So it also depends on your definition of "backward compatibility".

Comment: Yes, backward compatibility means that there are no behavioral differences, in this case.